# How the Looper knows to send the message to Handler?

Tags: android, android-handler

The question is, where I tell my Thread to use **mHandler** for the **Looper**?

Thank you.
I am using the below code:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;
    public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just after when you finish all the task that you have to perform on thread call 'handler'.........and perform all the task that you have to perform after Thread operation in handler...!!!Am i up-to what you required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The question is, where I tell my Thread to use mHandler for the
>   Looper?

You don't need to tell it explicitly, because the system (framework) does it for you. When you instantiate the `Handler`, it will automatically obtain access to the message queue of your current `Thread`. Quoting your comment:

> How the system know to send the message to the `mHandler` `Handler`?

I'll detail it below.

This is the constructor of `android.os.Handler` in Android:

```
    mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
    if (mLooper == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()");
    }
    mQueue = mLooper.mQueue;
```

As you can see, first it obtains the `Looper` of your current `Thread`. The source code of `Looper.myLooper()` is as follows:

```
public static final Looper myLooper() {
    return (Looper)sThreadLocal.get();
}
```

It obtains it from the thread local storage. Later, when you send a `Message` with this `Handler`, the `Handler` actually sets itself as the **recipient** of the `Message`: this is how the `Looper` will know where to dispatch the `Message` when it arrives. In details:

When you call `mHandler.sendMessage()`, eventually this code runs (among many other code lines):

```
    MessageQueue queue = mQueue;
    boolean sent = false;
    if (queue != null) {
        msg.target = this; // msg is your Message instance
        sent = queue.enqueueMessage(msg, uptimeMillis);
    }
```

As you can see, it sets the `Handler` instance as the target of the `Message`. So, later, when the `Message` is dispatched, it will contain the `Handler` as its target. This is how the `Looper` will know which `Handler` it should dispatch it to. In details, when you call `Looper.loop()`, the following happens for each of your `Message` instances in the queue:

```
msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
```

The `dispatchMessage()` code is the following:

```
public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.callback != null) {
        handleCallback(msg);
    } else {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            if (mCallback.handleMessage(msg)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Notice the **last** `handleMessage(msg)` call -- this is exactly your `handleMessage(msg)` override!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now me and everyone can understand it.

Comment: Hi @ThomasCalc, could you please help answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914966/how-to-get-the-amount-of-specified-message-which-not-handled-by-handler-in-andro

Answer (score 5):

To have a better understanding, create a normal `Thread` and try creating a `Handler` in the `run()` method of that thread. You'll get a `RuntimeException` saying:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   `Looper.prepare()`

Now calling Looper.prepare() in the `run()` method before creating a `Handler` would create a new `Looper` object *associated with the calling thread*. The source of your confusion is that Looper.prepare() does not take a `Thread` as argument. It need not, since it's a static method, which internally gets the `ThreadLocal` of the currently running thread. There can be at most one `Looper` associated with any `Thread`.

Now, calling `new Handler()` would associate the new `Handler` object with the `Looper` of the current `Thread` by internally calling `Looper.myLooper()`. You can create more than one `Handler` each with its own Callback in the same Thread. All Handlers would get their messages from the message queue of the same `Looper`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell anything. From the [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) documentation:

> Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that
>   thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to
>   the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it - from
>   that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message
>   queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

The handler is automatically bound to the thread's message queue. You only implement the callback, and **the system** will take care of everything, ie dispatching and processing the messages. Actually I agree that, using two static methods like `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` and automatically infer things, makes the pattern feels like black magic :)

Comment: But, can I chanhe mHandler, to other name? How the system know to send the message to the mHandler Handler?

Comment: You can name it whatever you like. The system knows the *thread* associated with the Handler, because of the surrounding calls to `Looper` methods. But the Handler, you have to specify it yourself. If you tell what your application does, I can make an example so you better understand