# How the method postDelayed(Runnable runnable, Long delayMilliSeconds) works exactly?

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler, postdelayed

I want to know when the method postDelayed(...) is executed and there are many messages that are waiting in the message queue. In that case, when the runnable will be runned ? is it gonna be after the time defined in the method elapses ? or it will wait until its role come in the message queue? or what... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check the source code and documentation:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached. The time-base is
>   uptimeMillis(). Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay
>   to execution.

```
public final boolean postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis) {
    return sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), delayMillis);
}
```

Now let's check `sendMessageDelayed`:

> Enqueue a message into the message queue after all pending messages
>   before (current time + delayMillis).

```
public final boolean sendMessageDelayed(Message msg, long delayMillis)
{
    if (delayMillis < 0) {
        delayMillis = 0;
    }
    return sendMessageAtTime(msg, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delayMillis);
}
```

So, postDelayed add your task to be executed after all pending messages but before uptime + the delay that you put.

Check this question for more explanation:
[Does postDelayed cause the message to jump to the front of the queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240015/does-postdelayed-cause-the-message-to-jump-to-the-front-of-the-queue)

Hope that it helps.

Comment: But what if the run of the pending messages take more than the delayMillis ?

Comment: check the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240015/does-postdelayed-cause-the-message-to-jump-to-the-front-of-the-queue

Comment: It's exactly what you wanna know.

Comment: Thank's Rodrigo, the links are so beneficial